# How to only keep time from Dataframe column of type Datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to extract only time from a datetime column but cannot find any solution. I am not good at string manipulation either.

Example:

## Datetime

---

2017-01-17 00:40:00
2017-01-17 01:40:00
2017-01-17 02:40:00
2017-01-17 03:40:00
2017-01-17 04:40:00

Desired Output:

## Time

---

00:40:00
01:40:00
02:40:00
03:40:00
04:40:00

Comment: `df['column_name'].dt.time`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [dt.time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '26-1-2014  04:40:00', 1: '26-1-2014  03:40:00', 2:'26-1-2015  02:40:00', 3:'30-1-2014  01:40:00'}}) 
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.time
```

This will add a time column

Comment: Thank you! it is the same solution @rafaelc suggested and it gives the output I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the column name for your datetime objects is called 'DatetimeColumn'. You can iterate over the Dataframe and modify the Datetime objects to just represent the time. Here is how you would modify them individually:

```
for row in df.rows:
    timeValue = row['DatetimeColumn'].strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```